# Wrong box being hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an array of links that when clicked will bring up a hidden div with information related to it.  Each link, when clicked, will bring up a different div associated with it.  I'm trying to make an image (closelabel.png) on every div with the class 'countystats' act as a close button to hide the divs.  I can't get the image in every div to act as a clickable link yet.  More importantly, when I click on link one nothing happens.  When I open up two hidden divs and try to close one, the opposite one closes (if I click on 'one' and 'two' to make the divs appear, and then I lick on the "a" (for purposes of a closing link) the opposite div is closed.  So the button for two closes one.

```
<style type="text/css">
.county{
    color:blue;
    display:block;

}
.countystats{
    background-image:url('../../../../../closelabel.png') ;
    background-position:top right;
    border:3px black inset;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:#ccc;
    display:none;
    right:250px;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
    width:200px;

}
</style>
```

---

```
<div style="height:250px;bottom:300px; width:100px; padding: 1em; overflow:auto; margin:5px 5px 5px 5px; border: 2px black;  overflow-x:hidden;">
    <a class="county" href="#">one</a>
    <a class="county" href="#">two</a>
    <a class="county" href="#">three</a>
    <a class="county" href="#">four </a>
    <a class="county" href="#">five</a>
    <a class="county" href="#">six</a>
</div>
<div class="countystats">stats one<p>woot</p><a  class="closediv" href="#">a</a></div>
<div class="countystats">stats two <a class="closediv"  href="#">a</a></div>

<div class="countystats">stats three</div>
<div class="countystats">some other stuff</div>
<div class="countystats">even more other stuff</div>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a.county').each( function(e){
        $(this).bind('click', function(e){
            var thisIs = $(this).index(); $('.countystats').eq(thisIs).show (250); 
        });
    });

    $('a.closediv').each( function(e){
        $(this).bind('click', function(e){
            var toClose = $(this).index(); $('.countystats').eq(toClose).hide(250); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/tbNvn/)

Comment: Why did you use 2 script tags?

Comment: Because I was doing this in a text editor without any script recognition or indenting and I wanted to make sure that I got my braces and semi colons right.

Comment: BTW, save yourself the headache and use a text editor that's suitable for coding. Regardless of OS, there are tons of good, free programs to choose from.

Comment: You're missing a `$(document).ready(...)`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is a bit of confusion about what `this` is in the click handler in here:

```
$('a.closediv').each( function(e){
    $(this).bind('click', function(e){
        var toClose = $(this).index();
        $('.countystats').eq(toClose).hide(250); 
    });
});
```

You're calling `index` on the `<a>` that you're using to hide the `<div>` rather than on the `<div>` itself.

The simplest solution is, as other people have noted, to use `closest`:

```
$('a.closediv').click(function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.countystats').hide(250);
});
```

No one else noticed what the real root of your problem was so I thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to bind event handlers incorrectly (for what you want the code to do). Also, just use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to figure out which element to hide.

```
$('a.county').click(function(e) {
    var thisIs = $(this).index();
    $('.countystats').eq(thisIs).show(250);
});

$('a.closediv').click(function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.countystats').hide(250);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/tbNvn/4/

Answer (score 0):

Just use parent():

```
$('a.county').click(function(e) {
    var thisIs = $(this).index();
    $('.countystats').eq(thisIs).show(250);
});

$('a.closediv').click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent().hide(250);
});
```